# Uploading a PDF in rails using Carrierwave and converting each page to a PNG/JPEG and saving them to a new model

Tags: file-upload, ruby-on-rails-3.1, carrierwave, pdf-conversion

I am fairly new to using carrierwave. Currently I can upload and perform simple actions on images, such as resize_to_fit.
 Now I need to change my name-uploader.rb file, so when I upload a PDF file, it automatically converts the pdf to a multiple image files (PNG/JPEG). One main thing I want to understand is how can I check the type of the file uploaded? I know I can set a list of file types to be accepted, I have already set a list of accepted file-types.
Now when a pdf is uploaded I want it to be converted to multiple images, and for each image a new model is created with certain data and the image.

- How to check the type of the file uploaded?
- How to convert the PDF into multiple image(PNG/JPEG/etc) files?
- Can I create models, or call an action from another controller to create the models using the generated pngs inside the uploader.rb file?
- Is Carrierwave the tool for this job or should I use another gem to upload files?

I have used the `convert => "png"` , but it was giving me an error.

*Note: I have included the RMagic is included at the top of the file.*

Thanks,

Comment: Babak,  Your questions are very vague and sounds like you just need to spend some time with Carrierwave. The level of details you need is very difficult to answer without asking a ton more architectural questions.

Comment: Checking the file type of the file uploaded is easy but depends on whether you are checking it in carrier wave or your model that implements the uploader.

Comment: Converting a PDF into multiple images -- are you thinking each PDF page would be an image or what?

Comment: Can I create models, or call an action from another controller to create the models using the generated pngs inside the uploader.rb file?  Use the Versions to create what you need.  The original file would be PDF and you can process each version to be a JPG OR PNG, but you'll have to learn how to use the ImageMagick libraries with manipulate method

Comment: Hey, I apologize for not being clear enough. Yes I was trying to do most of work inside the uploader file(CarrierWave). I was able to use the version and manipulate methods to convert a pdf into multiple pngs, then create new models and feed the images to the new model, but storing to new model is not working correctly, I am doing it wrong. I am having trouble with writing contidions for the file uploaded.

Comment: Yes I am trying to convert a PDF so that each page becomes a separate Image.

Comment: I have copied the code I am working with to a gist, it would be good if you could point out what I am doing wrong. **[Code](https://gist.github.com/2517376)**.
Thanks again.

Comment: I'm kind of confused by your code. I'm trying to do the same thing, but why does the uploader only save the files in the right directory if it's called from a version thingy? I tried to do something like

`process :converting`

which doesn't put the files in the right place.

Comment: @Ibrahim, based on what I understand, Process :converting runs before everything, and performs different procedures on the file uploaded, this occurs even before the model is created. So because the model is not created yet, there is no model.id therefore the location it is saved in is not correct. I got a working code now, although there is a hacky method to change the name to .png I will share it here soon.

Comment: responded to your gist, but I think you have to make sure to utilize the methods provided by carrier wave then it would save in the correct spot. I'll comment on the gist to see if I can help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try http://documentcloud.github.com/docsplit/

Comment: While your link my answer the question, you should post the relevant information here.